# Easy way to draw a few specific grid lines in bold?

Tags: altair

I have a scatter plot centered around an origin. I want to draw the origin grid lines (one horizontal line, one vertical) in bold to make it easier to see where the origin is.

I can make two separate [rule](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/candlestick_chart.html) charts, each with one line in them, and lay them under my scatter plot, but that's annoying. Is there an easier way?

```
extent = 1.0
scale = alt.Scale(domain=(-extent, extent))
base = alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame([[0, -extent, extent]])).mark_rule()
xaxis = base.encode(
    alt.Y('0:Q', scale=scale),
    alt.X('1:Q'),
    alt.X2('2:Q'),
)
yaxis = base.encode(
    alt.X('0:Q', scale=scale),
    alt.Y('1:Q'),
    alt.Y2('2:Q'),
)
xaxis + yaxis + scatter
```

Answer (score 1):

`domainWidth` in the `configure_axisX` or `configure_axisY` sets the thickness of the 'axis line':

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60, clip=False).transform_calculate(
    x = alt.datum.Horsepower-100,
    y = alt.datum.Miles_per_Gallon - 25
).encode(
    x=alt.X('x:Q', axis=alt.Axis(offset=-150)),
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', axis=alt.Axis(offset=-190)),
    color='Origin',
).configure_axisX(
    domainWidth =3
).configure_axisY(
    domainWidth =3
)
```